# Is it normal to have all java swing gui in one class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am just starting out with swing development and am having an issue. Is it normal to put the entire GUI into a single class? The application that I am building has one single JFrame that displays multiple different "pages". For example if the user clicks on a button they are taken to an entirely different page with a different layout. I've configured a Card Layout, and the one card that I have build so far uses the GridBag layout.

**The question that I have, then, is**
1.  whether or not each page should have its own class?
2. If they do how do I communicate between the GUI controller which runs the card layout and the individual pages?
3. Or should I just put all of the GUI into the GUI controller and let it run like that.

Below is the code for what I have so far, I am new to this and really would like to get good at it so if you spot any major issues that I missed please feel free to point them out.

Code for the individual page:

```
public class HomePage extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private GridBagLayout gl;
    private JPanel frm;
    JButton newPersonalContact;
    HomePage(){
         frm=new JPanel();
         gl=new GridBagLayout();
         GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
         frm.setLayout(gl);

         newPersonalContact=new JButton("New Personal Contact");
         JButton newBusinessContact=new JButton("New Business Contact");
         JButton showAllContacts=new JButton("Show All Contacts");
         JButton saveAndQuit=new JButton("Save and Quit");

         JPanel top=new JPanel();
         top.setBackground(new Color(218,165,32));
         top.add(new JLabel("Western Governers University Presents:"));


         JPanel middle=new JPanel();
         middle.setBackground(new Color(43,37,85));
         GridLayout ge=new GridLayout(4,4);
         middle.setLayout(ge);

         middle.add(new JLabel(""));
         middle.add(new JLabel(""));
         middle.add(new JLabel(""));
         middle.add(new JLabel(""));
         middle.add(new JLabel(""));
         middle.add(newPersonalContact);


         middle.add(newBusinessContact);
         middle.add(new JLabel(""));
         middle.add(new JLabel(""));
         middle.add(showAllContacts);

         middle.add(saveAndQuit);
         middle.add(new JLabel(""));middle.add(new JLabel(""));
         middle.add(new  JLabel(""));
         middle.add(new JLabel(""));

         JPanel bottom=new JPanel();
         bottom.setBackground(new Color(218,165,32));

         gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
         gbc.weightx=1.0;

         gbc.weighty=2.0;
         gbc.gridx=0;
         gbc.gridy=0;
         frm.add(top,gbc);

         gbc.weighty=6.0;
         gbc.gridx=0;
         gbc.gridy=1;
         frm.add(middle,gbc);

         gbc.weighty=1.0;
         gbc.gridx=0;
         gbc.gridy=2;
         frm.add(bottom,gbc);

         newPersonalContact.addActionListener(this);
         newBusinessContact.addActionListener(this);
         showAllContacts.addActionListener(this);
         saveAndQuit.addActionListener(this);


}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if (ae.getSource()==newPersonalContact){
        //What goes here?
    }

}
public JPanel getFrame(){
    return frm;
}

}
```

code for the GUI controller:

```
public class GUIController {
    JFrame frm;
    CardLayout cl;
    Container pane;
GUIController(){
frm=new JFrame();
frm.setSize(800,600);
frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel card2=new JPanel();
card2.setBackground(Color.black);

JPanel cards=new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(new HomePage().getFrame(), "Home");
cards.add(card2,"New Personal Contact");
pane=frm.getContentPane();
pane.add(cards,BorderLayout.CENTER);





}
public void start(){
    this.frm.setVisible(true);

}
public void showCard(){
    cl.show(pane, "Card2");
}


}
```

While this is for a school Project, the GUI interface is not required just something I am interested in learning. Thanks for any help.

Comment: After a little research I went with a mediator pattern as suggested. It finally works and isn't as complicated as I made it out to be. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't recommend to put all GUI code in class - at least if it gets big and does several things.

In that case use the Mediator pattern:

- put subcomponents to custom subclasses of JPanel
- that subclass listens for events of its children and updates other children
- fires own custom events if needed

Also note: If you're about to learn GUI programming and don't have a specific requirement to use Swing, consider to use the newer GUI toolkit [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/).

Comment: Any chance you would know a good place I can get an in depth example of the mediator pattern in action?

Answer (score 3):

If the GUI class gets big and unwieldy it is practical to divide it into several classes.

One way to do that would be to create one class for each "page". Let the HomePage class have instance variables that hold references to the "page" objects.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. You mean I should have one class that contains objects created from the other "page" classes right?