# Dynamically add jcheckbox in jpanel

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have to add dynamically jcheckboxes in a panel when the user write something into a form. That's my code

## Main

```
public class EmptyFrame extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*top panels*/
    //to add technicians
    private JButton newTechnician;
    private NewTechForm ntForm;
    private JPanel panelForm;
    private JPanel panelChekBoxes;
    TechCheckBoxGroup techniciansGroup;
    private List<String> technicians;
    //main container
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    //components
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);

    EmptyFrame(){
        preinit();
        init();
    }
    private void preinit(){
        panelChekBoxes=new JPanel();
        panelForm=new JPanel();
        techniciansGroup=new TechCheckBoxGroup(panelChekBoxes);
    }
    private void init(){
        /*top options*/
        ntForm=new NewTechForm(panelForm);            
        newTechnician=new JButton("Add technician");
        newTechnician.addActionListener(
                      new AddTechnicianAction(techniciansGroup,ntForm)
                      );
        ntForm.getPanel().add(newTechnician);
        /*end top options*/

        for(String technic : technicians){
            techniciansGroup.addCheckBoxes(
                                 new JCheckBox(technic));       
        }
        createWindowLayout(
                new JLabel("Technicians"),
                techniciansGroup.getCheckBoxes(),
                ntForm.getPanel());
    }
    public void createWindowLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        pane = getContentPane();
        gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);        
        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(arg[0])
                        .addComponent(arg[1])
                        .addComponent(arg[2])
                        )
        );
        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(arg[0])
                    .addComponent(arg[1])
                    .addComponent(arg[2]))
            );
        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                EmptyFrame ex = new EmptyFrame();
                ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

in the main are presents a form and a checkbox group the first is the ntForm and the second one is the techniciansGroup. When i insert a name inside the form i would like to add a checkbox inside the checkbox group, here are the button, the checkbox group and the form classes:

## AddTechnicianAction

this would be the class where everything would happened

```
public class AddTechnicianAction implements ActionListener{

    TechCheckBoxGroup technicians;
    NewTechForm form;
    JTable table;

    public AddTechnicianAction(TechCheckBoxGroup arg0, NewTechForm arg1){
        technicians=arg0;
        form=arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Add new tech: "+this.form.getSurnameText().getText()+" "+this.form.getNameText().getText());
        technicians.addCheckBoxes(new JCheckBox(this.form.getSurnameText()+" "+this.form.getNameText()));
        System.out.println(technicians);
    }

}
```

## NewTechForm

this is the form

```
public class NewTechForm {

    private JLabel  nameLabel;
    private JLabel  surnameLabel;
    private JTextField nameText;
    private JTextField surnameText;
    private JPanel panel;

    public NewTechForm(JPanel panel){
        nameLabel= new JLabel("Nome: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        surnameLabel = new JLabel("Cognome:  ", JLabel.CENTER);
        nameText = new JTextField(6);
        surnameText = new JTextField(6);
        this.panel=panel;
        panel.add(nameLabel);
        panel.add(nameText);
        panel.add(surnameLabel);
        panel.add(surnameText);

    }

    public JLabel getNameLabel() {
        return nameLabel;
    }

    public JTextField getNameText() {
        return nameText;
    }

    public JTextField getSurnameText() {
        return surnameText;
    }

    public JLabel getSurnameLabel() {
        return surnameLabel;
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

}
```

The problem is that inside TechCheckBoxGroup something happens, but not the things that i'm expecting to. The panel have a new checkbox after the action is performed but it seems that that panel (the obne inside TachCheckBoxGroup) is not the one inside the main class, and infact nothing were rendered in the window. There is clearly something that i didn't understand about the scoping in swing, what's the better practice to do what i'm trying to? Or this is the good way and i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is important to have answers on stack overflow, so for that reason I post my answer to my problem even if it's not really easy to see that was the right solution, now I explain better. While I'm trying to solve the problem of the wrong behaviour I've asked my self if I was doing the wrong considerations, and so it was, because i was trying to let comunicate all the components without a real

> mediator

in fact it was impossible to catch the event in the main window with the code that i had written above. Seaching and searching i finally find this great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626543/is-it-normal-to-have-all-java-swing-gui-in-one-class). So i basically change the NewTechForm classes making it a jpanel with a form inside, same thing for the CheckGroupBox, i'll made it a panel with the check box inside, and i send all the event to a listener in the main window.